# Can a twist-off bottle be capped?

Tags: bottling, capping, equipment, techniques

Out of curiosity (and appreciation for [Boulevard's bottle's form-factor](http://www.blvdbeer.com/beer.htm)), can a twist-off bottle be reliably capped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done it a few times by accident, and it worked fine each time, but the risk of an air leak is too great to do it on purpose, in my opinion...

Comment: I wonder, if you did it on purpose, if that would make it bad for sure. Double blind experiments and all that ;)

Comment: Skrambled is right.  It is something you CAN do, but in general it's bad practice.  Besides, even new bottles are cheap and if you make a deal with the local bartender, you should be able to pick up a ton of non-twistoffs for re-use.  Provided you are not in a deposit state, that is.

Answer (score 5):

Not reliably.  The threads for the twist cap don't allow for a pop cap to securely fasten and will let the beer go flat very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, twist-off bottles are also made of thinner glass and are more susceptible to breakage.  There's a higher risk of breaking the neck off when capping and also of the bottle cracking or breaking under the pressure of carbonation.  I'd avoid using twist-off bottles.

Answer (score 2):

I've bottle many beers in twist off's and have had no problems at all. There is also the added benefit of twisting off the cap when they're ready to drink. I recommend them.
mark
www.backyardbrewer.blogspot.com
www.thebackyardbrewer.com

Comment: Interesting. No trouble with breaking them like JackSmith mentioned?

Comment: Haven't had that experience yet.<br />
mark<br />
www.backyardbrewer.blogspot.com<br />
www.thebackyardbrewer.com

Comment: I haven't had that experience yet.
mark